# React Native auth0 'access_denied' 'unauthorized' error

Tags: reactjs, react-native, authentication, oauth-2.0, auth0

I am trying to add auth0 authentication to my React Native app. I am following this quickstart guide: https://auth0.com/docs/quickstart/native/react-native

I am connecting to a "Regular Web App" application set up by a client, and am running the following code:

```
auth0
    .webAuth
    .authorize({scope: 'openid profile email', audience: 'https://YOUR_DOMAIN/userinfo'})
```

(`YOUR_DOMAIN` is replaced with my domain)

It successfully loads the auth0 universal login screen. If I type in a wrong username or password it notifies me. When I type in the correct username/password, it closes the auth0 universal login screen and returns to my app, but it gives me the following error:

```
AuthError {
  name: "access_denied",
  message: "Unauthorized",
  json: Object,
  status: 401,
  stack: "Error↵    at responseHandler (blob:file:///7a27baf…:///7a27baff-5c83-48e3-a170-0137ed982e99:2563:13)"
}
```

I know from the stack trace that this error is thrown by the `authorize()` method.

Any ideas where this might be coming from?

Thanks!

Comment: Facing same issue, wondering if you found a solution

Comment: Any news ?? I face it too